# Returing null value using all_to_array in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I was facing a problem with all_to_array. It's returning a null value.

```
 $object_self = new self();

            $response = $object_self->
    select('DATE(`created_at`) as `day`')->select_min('paid_amount','min_amount')
->get('orders');

             $query_object = $response->all_to_array(array(
                                                                'day',
                                                                'min_amount',

                                                   ));
```

The $query_object is a null value all though the query is correct.

Comment: You probably have an sql error, check what `print get_instance()->db->last_query();` outputs. Did you get any? I suspect that the `select('DATE(\`created_at\`) as day')` in this form wont work, you might have to disable column escaping with a second `false` parameter there.

Comment: the output of the print statement is SELECT DATE(`created_at`) as day what does this mean

Comment: Try coping the whole sql statement into your sql console and see if it runs ok, just to see if you got any sql error.

Comment: Sir the sql query is wrking properly ... I am able to get the outputs of this thing

Comment: Syntax of all_to_array .... is it crrt ???

Comment: It seems ok to me, i'm out of ideas at this point. Do you use wanwizard's datamapper library? Might worth to add it as a tag so the right people find your question.